# Convert every two elements in an indexed array to form an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => john
    [2] => last
    [3] => doe
    [4] => company
    [5] => sony
)
```

I need to convert to this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => john
    [last] => doe
    [company] => sony
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i += 2)
    $newArray[ $myArray[$i] ] = $myArray[$i+1];
```

Comment: This will throw `Notice: undefined offset` if you have an array with an odd number of elements. Also `count($myArray)` will be calculated each loop, that will cause problems with bigger arrays

Comment: @kingkero Thanks for comment, you are right. I presumed array will be well formatted, in order not to complicate the answer.

Comment: @Martinsos I've an Array([0] => shiva  [1] => kumar    [2] => shrestha) and want to convert like Array([first_name] => shiva    [middle_name] => kumar   [last_name] => shrestha) What should I do for solving such problem?

Comment: @Martinsos I got my answer! $keys = array('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name'); $employee = array('shiva', 'kumar', 'shrestha'); $employee = array_combine($keys, $employee); Problem Resolved!